# cumsum with condition of different column?

Tags: python, pandas

i have data.

| timestamp | id1 | id2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1383265800000 | 10 | 1 | 3.214243229598746E-5 |
| 1383265800000 | 1 | 10 | 2.814243229598746E-5 |

when timestamp is equal, and id1[0] == id2[1] and id1[1] == id2[0] then merge into

| timestamp | id1 | id2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1383265800000 | 1 | 10 | 6.028E-5 |

original code is below, working on test data, but not on original data.

```py
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df) - 1):
        if (df.iloc[i, 0] == df.iloc[j, 0]) and \
                (df.iloc[i, 1] == df.iloc[j, 2]) and \
                (df.iloc[j, 1] == df.iloc[i, 2]):
            df.iloc[i, 3] = df.iloc[i, 3] + df.iloc[j, 3]
            df.drop(index=[j], inplace=True, axis=0)
```

Comment: I think you cannot do what you want because you are dropping line from your data on the way. As you are using for loop, it will surely causes issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use two for loop instead of one

Something like :

```
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df) - 1):
        if (df.iloc[i, 0] == df.iloc[j, 0]) and \
                (df.iloc[i, 1] == df.iloc[j, 2]) and \
                (df.iloc[j, 1] == df.iloc[i, 2]):
            df.iloc[i, 3] = df.iloc[i, 3] + df.iloc[j, 3]

linetoremove = []
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df) - 1):
        if (df.iloc[i, 0] == df.iloc[j, 0]) and \
                (df.iloc[i, 1] == df.iloc[j, 2]) and \
                (df.iloc[j, 1] == df.iloc[i, 2]):
            linetoremove.append(j)
 df.drop(index=linetoremove, inplace=True, axis=0)
```